# Parsing xml with column name and value in separate elements with AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue

Hi I have a ton of XML files from an external source that have to be parsed into a database. 
They look like this:

```
<root>
  <object id="123">
    <attributes>
      <attribute>
        <type>foo</type>
        <value>bar</value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
        <type>qwe</type>
        <value>asd</value>
      </attribute>
    </attributes>
  </object>
</root>
```

The most obvious way would be using "object" as classifier but than I have no idea how to map the attributes to columns and their values. Another way I tried is using attribute as classifier but than I'm not much closer to solving the key value problem and I'm missing the object Id.
I'm starting to thing it might be better to pre-format the XML to a more usable format first outside of glue.

Answer (score 0):

I see an aws-glue tag. Looks like they have something for handling XML?: [aws-glue-programming-etl-format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html)

Per this, "I'm starting to thing it might be better to preformat the XML to a more usable format first outside of glue", maybe converting to json would help? You can find many tools for this online.